Could use some help understanding the purpose of CR3 and CR4
I could use a little help understanding the purpose of CR3 and CR4 in the circuit below. While I believe CR1 and CR2 are used to bias Q1 and Q2 respectively, I cannot figure out what CR3 and CR4 are doing...
Also, I am not sure if it's just a drafting error but it appears that the opamp has no negative feedback, so the gain must be terribly high for that stage.
Thanks in advance! Very much appreciated...
Image Source:
Website:  SteamPowerRadio.com
Product: SDA-8A Stereo Distribution Amplifier
Document URL: https://steampoweredradio.com/pdf/pr&e/manuals/sda-8a%20distribution%20amplifier.pdf  (Page 30 of 32)


Mark Bruno - Hi, Where did that image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY (More site rules in the [tour] & [help].)

This circuit looks like it's designed to be used with external negative feedback applied--it's pretty much just a current-boosting output stage attached to an NE5534 (a generic op amp from the 80s that's outperformed by numerous cheaper alternatives these days).

Added required image source info - Sorry about that!...

(What I find puzzling is C6 being where it is.)

They're there to protect the base-emitter junction in the output transistors (Q1,Q2) from being reverse-biased enough to damage them.
Without knowing how this amplifier is intended to be used I can't say exactly what could cause that.
